# Resetting push notification settings for an iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, push, reset

I initially setup my app in sandbox mode using the code below, I forgot to add **UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
```

I have reset the app by moving the clock a day forward, as mentioned here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html, but when I try to add the **UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert** it still only initiaites the **badge** and **sound alert**, I can't add the **alert**.....

I've even tried a new app id and a new provisioning profile, but the problem persists, what can i do to fix this?

Comment: show your payload you are sending to APNS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly you have to move up a day or two **AND** restart your device.